# is possible deploy a Django project with a App instead a Droplet in DigitalOcean?

Tags: django, deployment

I need to deploy a Django application, but I only find tutorials using droplets on DigitalOcean, I would like to know if it is possible to deploy it through an App

I followed the instructions from this repository, https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Try-Django-3.2, but it didn't work for me

Comment: A 5 second Google search returns the following result: https://docs.digitalocean.com/developer-center/deploy-a-django-app-on-app-platform/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a droplet with django stack.
Then, if you have existing django project, upload/deploy your django project to droplet using ssh `rsync` or using the `git and ci/cd` feature

Django stack on digitalocean tutorial can view [here](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/django-3-2-lts), flow user->nginx->django->postgresql.